# Deal with extremely large numbers with Python Programming

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

When we are talking about complexity of our codes most of time we consider about the number of inputs. Usually we don't much consider about under laying hardware implementation. To get a connectivity between  complexity of code and number of input which we compose to our algorithm(Code) we use Big_O notation commonly . loop are essential thing to implement algorithm but it has O(n) complexity which means time will grow linearly with number of input so large number of inputs it inefficient. but we can replace loop by recursion cause recursion always has O(log n) time complexity .And i am not going to clarify it on here . From all of these above But i want to say recursion is more efficient than loop

and also any thing which can do loop we can do that same thing by recursion more efficiently.

so i found a Question from [Project Euler.net](https://projecteuler.net/problem=48) call [self powers](https://projecteuler.net/problem=48)

follow is my Question

**The series, 11 + 22 + 33 + ... + 1010 = 10405071317.
Find the last ten digits of the series, 11 + 22 + 33 + ... + 10001000.**

this Question seems easy so i implement my code from Python and its *work smoothly for **small number** of number ranges* but  getting power of 1000 to 1000 and sum of all above python usually show a error (cause that numbers are extremely larger which enough to occur in memory flow in python) so how do i get the answer. follow is my code

```
def f(n):
    if n==1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n**n+f(n-1)
```

So my Question is How do i solve this problem,and how to i deal with those extremely large number , how do i manage those exception which will occur on large number of integers please mention good motivative algorithm?

Comment: Where did you find this "recursion always has O(log n) time complexity"?

Comment: @vish4071 single implementation of  recursion has  O(log n)

Comment: 1. Recusion doesn't always have `O(logn)` time complexity. 2. Loops don't necessarily have O(n) complexity e.g this one: `for(int i = 1; i < N; i *=2)`

Comment: Why Those people devoting my question instead giving an answer

Comment: One part of project Euler is to come with smart algorithms that bypass things as extremely large numbers of large computation times. Perhaps you'll want to look at it in another way, more mathematically, to find an algorithm without the straightforward large number calculation.

Comment: Why do you use powers and recursion when it's a straightforward sum?

Comment: @ Evert  thanks you are great .others try to find mistakes in my question insted you give me an idea thanks  Evert

Comment: What is single implementation?

Comment: Your premise is wrong. You are assuming - based on wrong facts - that recursion is always more efficient than loops, which is simply not the case. Most of the times you should avoid using recursion and choose the iterative approach because recusion uses a lot more memory and depending on the problem you might be recalculating the same result over and over again.

Comment: @Heathens "Why Those people devoting my question instead giving an answer" Because stackoverflow is not just a website where you come to get an answer. It is aimed at archiving the questions and the answers, so that someone asking themselves the same question can find answers already existing, and that have been improved over time. Hence the "edit" function. But questions have to be of good quality too, in order to be useful. In your question, you claim things that are either wrong or not always true, which might give wrong knowledge to the readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing that makes recursion inherently more efficient. Moreover, the same algorithm implemented with recursion is likely to be *less* efficient due to function call overhead. Worse than that, and this is exactly your case, using recursions of large depth is likely to cause stack overflow (no pun intended). Unless tail-recursion optimization is in use, which is not in Python.

Python does not have any limits (within reasonable ranges) of integer number size, and this is not the problem. Re-implement the function using a loop, and you'll do fine. Except that `n ** n` does not do what you seem to think it does.

Comment: @vish4071 try and behold.

Comment: Sorry...my bad @bereal

Comment: Oh yea........!!! thanks @bereal your genius